# URLSpan in Spannable string

Tags: android, spannablestring

I tried URLSpan in scannable string like this

```
        private void setSmsText() {

                SpannableString string = new SpannableString("Text with a url span");
    string.setSpan(new URLSpan("http://www.developer.android.com"), 12, 15, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

    sms_text.setText(string);
    sms_text.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());


    }
```

Here while commenting the setMovementMethod line the text appears to be clickable(url format)
[image: While Comenting]

but when uncommenting the text is not clickable

[image: After Comenting]

I am not able to navigate to the url by clicking on the text

Comment: @pskink the text appears to be plain when it is uncommented

as shown in pics

Comment: @pskink even by using LinkMovementMethod why  there is no transition

Comment: modified the code with the example from android developer site
        'SpannableString string = new SpannableString("Text with a url span");
        string.setSpan(new URLSpan("http://www.developer.android.com"), 12, 15, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);'

still the same behaviour

Comment: This text is passed from server side and only a portion should be used for url purpose

linkify is for making the whole text a link right? 

so can't use linkify

Comment: no, `Linkify` does not work that way - read the official [Linkify docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/util/Linkify) for more info

Comment: Had enabled autolink:web

disabling it solved my issue

@pskink thanks for help and will read abt linkify more

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString(YOUR_TEXT);
        ClickableSpan clickableSpan = new ClickableSpan() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View widget) {
                //your code like open webview or any other
            }
        };

spannableString.setSpan(clickableSpan, YOUR_TEXT_STARTING_INDEX,YOUR_TEXT_END_INDEX , Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

let me know if this work or not

Comment: Using clickable span will work

but URLSpan has the default action to move to the page 

Am I right?